# Magento, how to move static blocks?

Tags: php, xml, magento, static-block

I'm new in magento and i'm using a theme(name: awesome) and i have several static blocks in a specific order
in html i can see my static blocks with this order:

```
<section class="slider-intro"></section>
<section class="main-col"></section>
<section class="our-features-box"></section>
<section class="brand-logo"></section>
```

i would like to change position and put my static block named as brand-logo in first. In magento, how can i do that?  there is any file where i can change this order manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look into your app/design/frontend/awesome/default/template/page/html/ folder and look for those strings. Folder structure may change, based on your theme.

Comment: @ermannob, i looked there but i can't find nothing, maybe is in a xml or in other folder..